# MS Access Report Layout

Tags: ms-access, layout, report, grouping

I have created a Report with grouped data, as seen in the top half of the image. I would ideally like the grouping to look like the bottom half of the image. Is this possible in Access, and if so, how do I achieve this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to place sections side-by-side in Access. Reports have a property `MoveLayout` that can be set to `False` in code. The result of this is that the next section will start to print at the same vertical position and thus print several sections overlayed on top of each other.

This is a code example from one of my reports where I set this property depending on a field value:

```vb
Private Sub GroupHeader2_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If FormatCount = 1 Then
        If IsNull(Me!Pruefpunkt) Then
            Me.MoveLayout = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You will probably have to set this property to `False` in the group sections headers and to true in the details section and group sections footers. Do this in the `Format` event of the sections.

---

**UPDATE** (in response to comment)

It works for me

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    MoveLayout = True
End Sub

Private Sub GroupHeader0_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    MoveLayout = False
End Sub

Private Sub GroupHeader1_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    MoveLayout = False
End Sub
```

With a report looking like this

[image]

The result looks like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: @Oliver I tried 'Me.MoveLayout = False' on the onFormat event of the group header and it didn't seem to do anything. Then I did the same on the onLoad event and it produced an invalid reference to the property exception. I'm sure your suggestion is on the right track but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: It actually worked out great. The event wasn't firing because apparently it only fires in print view. And to think I was just about to go through the nightmare of making this as a cross-tab. I'd give you more upvotes if I could :) Many thanks.

Comment: What I show above is actually a print preview. The code of cause never runs in design mode in Access; therefore you will never see the resulting effect in design mode.

Comment: The code also doesn't run in Report/Form view ether, even though other events do run. The onFormat event will only run in print preview.

Comment: This cannot be. Are you sure that the Event is linked to the procedures? Look if you see `[Event Procedure]` in the properties window next to `On Format`. If you just copied my code this might not be the case, if your sections have a different name (possibly because you are using a different language Access).